# The best way to find a rate for a cost function

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, time-complexity, regression

I have 2 arrays: the first array contains areas of flats and the second its prices. The values of arrays form a chart and will be used to calculate results of a cost function. The main task is to find the best parameter of the cost function to minimize its result. This is how the cost function looks like:

[image]

It was suggested creating a loop from 1 to 10 000 and find the best parameter that has less result. The complexity of this algorithm is 10 000 * size of the arrays.

I proposed an idea to calculate differences between corresponding elements of the arrays and put results into an array. Then find an average of all elements of this array. The obtained average value is the parameter which should provide a better result for our cost function. The algorithm is much more efficient than previous one and can provide more accurate results.

I am wondering whether my algorithm is applicable or not?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this cost function is? I'm not sure I follow what you're saying.

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow's image uploader doesn't work... I managed only to provide a link: http://imageshack.com/a/img924/3743/b2v2LZ.png. In this function: 
m - the length of an array;
x(i) - i element of the 1st array;
y(i) - i element of the 2st array;
a - the parameter which I need to calculate;

Comment: What are Theta_0 and Theta_1 here?

Comment: I took it from another example, we don't need theta 0 and 1 here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost function that you're proposing is the mean squared error of fitting a linear function to a collection of data points. This is a well-studied problem, and in fact there's a closed-form solution that will tell you the mathematically optimal value of a that you should pick. In that sense, I would recommend not using *either* of the solutions that are proposed here and to instead just solve things directly.

The cost function you have is a function purely of the variable a, so taking the derivative with respect to a, setting that derivative to zero, and solving should give you the optimal choice of a.

> Cost(a) = (1 / 2m) Σ<sub>i=0</sub>(ax<sub>i</sub> - y<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup>
>
> Cost'(a) = (1 / 2m) Σ<sub>i=0</sub>2(ax<sub>i</sub> - y<sub>i</sub>)x<sub>i</sub>
>
> Cost'(a) = (1 / 2m) Σ<sub>i=0</sub>(2ax<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> - 2x<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i</sub>)

Setting this expression to 0 and simplifying tells us that

> 0 = (1 / 2m) Σ<sub>i=0</sub>(2ax<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> - 2x<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i</sub>)
>
> 0 = Σ<sub>i=0</sub>(2ax<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> - 2x<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i</sub>)
>
> 0 = 2a Σ<sub>i=0</sub>x<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> - 2Σ<sub>i=0</sub>x<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i</sub>
>
> a Σ<sub>i=0</sub>x<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> = Σ<sub>i=0</sub>x<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i</sub>
>
> a = (Σ<sub>i=0</sub>x<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i</sub>) / (Σ<sub>i=0</sub>x<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>)

You should be able to compute this pretty easily in time O(n) by making a single pass over the array and computing the numerator and denominator

Comment: Are you sure that you got right derivative? I think should be like 
Cost'(a) = (1 / 2m) Σi=0 2(ax-y) ( http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-y)%5E2 )

Comment: @DenisEvseev No, that won't necessarily work. Think of it this way - you're looking for a scaling factor to scale up the entire first array by. Subtracting the first and the second array elements in pairs tells you very little about the scaling factor you need. Imagine the x's are measured in trillions and the y's are in single digits. The differences will be staggering, but the a you want is tiny in that case.

Comment: Many thanks @templatetypedef! There is only 1 moment.  Could you please clarify how did you manage to obtain the derivative:
Σi=0(2axi2 - 2xiyi). Whereas based on rules and wolframapha:
Where: (wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-y)%5E2 )
Cost'(a) = (1 / 2m) Σi=0 2x - 2y

Comment: (ax - y)^2 = a^2x^2 - 2axy + y^2. Taking the derivative with respect to a gives 2ax^2 - 2xy. (I’m ignoring the leading constant term for now.) We’re taking the derivative with respect to a, not x.